# First tab always selected in stacked ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` with 2+ tabs. Initially I don't want any of the tabs to be selected. When in landscape on a `handset` or on a `Tablet` it works as expected and when `debugging` I can see that selected tab is `null`. However, when running code on handset in `portrait` the `ActionBar` is stacked and the first tab looks like it is selected. Debugging shows that `onTabSelected` in the `TabListener` is never called and the selected tab is null during `onCreate` and `onResume`.

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(tabListener).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_1), false);
getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(tabListener).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_2), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially I don't want any of the tabs to be selected.

That is not supported, unless you have no tabs. It is also a bizarre UI request -- I can think of zero other environments where a set of tabs has no selection.

Comment: Well, its really a separate activity displaying the start/home page of the app. From there the user can see what options (the tabs) to select from. When clicking the tabs a new activity is started and the appropriate tab is selected. There is of course the option of adding buttons instead of the tabs, either embedded in the layout or as options from the actionbar, but the decision was to make it look like tabs so that it looks the same to the user. Any suggestions on how to get around the problem?

Funny thing it was working fine while we we're only supporting 'not narrow' layouts.

Comment: @user2282819: "Well, its really a separate activity displaying the start/home page of the app." -- then the solution would be to get rid of this activity and send them somewhere meaningful first. Do not send the user to an activity that exists solely to take them to other activities. Tabs are also an inappropriate UI metaphor here: they are to show different things *in the same activity*, not to represent *completely different activities*.

Comment: The start activity is used for displaying a lot of information as well and the tabs are used as short cuts to take the user to the real tab activity. I can see your point with the tabs being wrong UI metaphor from the start page, but when selected they do show different cuts/perspectives of the same data set within the same activity. I'm greatful if you can point me in a better direction of what UI metaphor to use from the start page.

Comment: @user2282819: Plain action bar items, or a sliding menu, are more typical for what you are describing. A bunch of apps use jfeinstein's sliding menu implementation: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

Comment: Thanks, I'll definately consider a redesign. 

For the moment I managed to get a hack working keeping the design as is. After initiating the ActionBar, first select a tab and then getActionBar().selectTab(null).